# Angular/NgRx Cannot find name 'on' when creating reducer

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I am trying to follow NgRx [documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/feature-creators) to implement createFeature feature which incldes creating a reducer with createReducer with on*s*, I am stuck on this compiler **error: Cannot find name 'on'.**

It relates to this piece of code:

```js
export const booksFeature = createFeature({
  name: 'books',
  reducer: createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(BookListPageActions.enter, (state) => ({
      ...state,
      loading: true,
    })),
    on(BooksApiActions.loadBooksSuccess, (state, { books }) => ({
      ...state,
      books,
      loading: false,
    }))
  ),
});
```

Package.json file bellow

```json
{
  "name": "calculator",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^14.3.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^14.3.2",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^14.3.2",
    "@schematics/angular": "^14.2.6",
    "mathjs": "^11.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^9.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should include `on` in your imports: `import { createFeature, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';`.  Looks like this is missing in the documentation example.

Answer (score 0):

The `createReducer`, `createFeature`, and `on` methods need to be imported from `@ngrx/store`.

```
import {createFeature,createReducer,on} from '@ngrx/store`

export const booksFeature = createFeature({
  name: 'books',
  reducer: createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(BookListPageActions.enter, (state) => ({
      ...state,
      loading: true,
    })),
    on(BooksApiActions.loadBooksSuccess, (state, { books }) => ({
      ...state,
      books,
      loading: false,
    }))
  ),
});
```